# AWS: Custom SSL certificate option is disabled in CloudFront, but I created a SSL certificate using AWS Certificate Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, https, ssl-certificate

I am creating a SSL certificate for my amazon S3 static website. I created a SSL certificate using Certificate Manager for my domain and its status is 'Issued'. I am creating a CloudFront Distribution, but the Custom SSL Certificate option is disabled.

Will it take some time (a day or more) before I can see my custom SSL certificate? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you create the certificate in the `us-east-1` region of Certificate Manager?

Comment: Yes, you were correct. Earlier, I created the certificate in Asia region. Now, after creating the certificate in us-east-1 region, I can see the certificate when I am creating a CloudFront. Should we create certificate only in us-east-1 region? You can write the above comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Certificates that will be used with an Application Load Balancer (ELB/2.0) need to be created in ACM in the same region as the balancer.

Certificates that will be used with CloudFront always need to be created in us-east-1.

> To use an ACM Certificate with Amazon CloudFront, you must request or import the certificate in the US East (N. Virginia) region. ACM Certificates in this region that are associated with a CloudFront distribution are distributed to all the geographic locations configured for that distribution.
>
> – http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-regions.html

The reason for this is that CloudFront doesn't follow the regional boundary model in AWS.  CloudFront edge locations are all over the globe, but are configured and managed out of us-east-1 -- think of it as CloudFront's home region.  Once a distribution reaches the `Deployed` state, it is not operationally dependent on us-east-1, but during provisioning, everything originates from that region, so that's the only ACM region that CloudFront can access.

Comment: I have the same problem.  I've imported the certificate in ACM in the N Viginia (us-east 1) region. The certificate shows up in the custom SSL option (when editing or creating a distribution) but it is still greyed out along with the radio button for selecting Custom SSL.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting this exact behavior but with the certificated correctly imported at us-east-1 and figured out that the problem was the key size of my certificate (4096 bits).

AWS CloudFront only accept keys up to 2048 bits, as stated here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cnames-and-https-requirements.html#https-requirements-size-of-public-key

> **Size of the Public Key**
>
> The length of the public key for a certificate depends on where you're storing it.
>
> Importing a certificate into AWS Certificate Manager (ACM): public key length must be 1024 or 2048 bits. The limit for a certificate that you use with CloudFront is 2048 bits, even though ACM supports larger keys.
>
> Uploading a certificate to the AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) certificate store: maximum size of the public key is 2048 bits.
>
> We recommend using 2048 bits.

Answer (score 2):

When replacing a cert, make sure you clear out the name of the existing cert in the 'Custom SSL Certificate (example.com)' text box. If you leave it uncleared, other certs are not selectable.

Answer (score 0):

Had thesame experience while trying to create a cloudFront distribution. I initially created the certificate in the us-west-2 region but the checkbox was greyed out. What resolved it was creating the certificate in the us-east-1 region. Checkbox immediately became selectable.