# Trouble getting my simple website to use SSL within SSL and CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-certificate-manager

I'm trying to install an SSL for my website hosted on an EC2, hosted in Ireland.  This article below states the load balancer needs to be hosted in n. virginia  for Cloud Front to work (so that I can use my custom SSL certificate).  Will this work if my website is in Ireland?

I've tried several times but yet to get it working.  I have the following - EC2, route53, load balancer, certificate manager, cloudfront.

[AWS: Custom SSL certificate option is disabled in CloudFront, but I created a SSL certificate using AWS Certificate Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166169/aws-custom-ssl-certificate-option-is-disabled-in-cloudfront-but-i-created-a-ss)

Many thanks,

**Updates**

Screenshot of my certificate

[image: certificate]

CloudFront

[image: CloudFront]

[image: route 53]

[image: cloudfront]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to have your load balancer hosted in North Virginia, this is referring to using AWS Certificate Manager and CloudFront together. I.e., if you want to request an SSL certificate using the AWS Certificate Manager and attach it to your CloudFront distribution.

This is because CloudFront distributes its SSL certificates from North Virginia out to the other edge locations in its distribution network.

What you can do is:

- ACM certificate created in North Virginia
- CloudFront distribution created and certificate applied to it
- Route 53 hosted zone with an Alias to CloudFront distribution
- Load balancer in Ireland set as an origin in CloudFront distribution
- EC2 instance in Ireland

Example of Alias in Route 53 pointing to CloudFront distribution:

[image]

Example of CloudFront DNS:

[image]

Comment: Ok, just trying now.  I've deleted the cloudfront distribution to start from fresh..  Just waiting for the status to finish whilst it's creating a new one

Comment: The Route 53 point in your answer, what type should it be?  "txt - text"

Comment: I would suggesting using the Alias type - when you select it, it should auto-populate with your CloudFront distribution (wait until it's fully provisioned).

Comment: I've added a screen shot showing what I mean regarding Route 53.

Comment: Can't see the cloud front in the dropdown with a value (cloudfront distribution has deployed).  The option is empty (like your screen shot)

Comment: Try just pasting in your CloudFront distributions DNS endpoint.

Comment: Do you mean the ARN value to paste?  (I've tried this but no luck)

Comment: No - the endpoint that you hit in a browser to hit your CloudFront distribution.

Comment: I've added pictures, hope that helps

Comment: Sorry not sure, do you mean my domain name?

Comment: The domain name of the CloudFront distribution, not the domain name of your certificate. See my latest update for an example - the red highlighted box is what you need to paste into your Alias in Route 53.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194347/discussion-between-chris-mckinnel-and-james).